# Push data to Salseforce app uing a .Net app

Tags: c#, salesforce

Net app to push data to a sales force app. I didn't find and dll or plugin that would help me to achieve this goal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different options, here are a few:

- [SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) - Get your org's enterprise.wsdl file from Salesforce by going to Setup > Develop > API > Generate Enterprise WSDL.  Then use Visual Studio to import the wsdl file to create proxy classes.
- [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm)
- [Bulk API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm)
- [Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader) (helpful for updating from .csv files)

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the suggestions, they really helped. It seems for my problem bulk API is the solution since I have large quantity of data need to be pushed. But currently I'm in trouble since there is not many useful material for the .Net side. But there are some in Java, but trying to do the steps in .Net give me exceptions, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more detail about the exceptions you're getting?  Maybe edit your original question as well, give us some detail on what you're trying to do